# Using the library JUNG graphs

Tags: java, jung

I use the JUNG java library to manage graphs and I want to know how to color the connected nodes with the same color to distinguish the connected components.

For example, I want the nodes `2`, `3` and `4` to have the same color and the node `1`to have another color, knowing that the adjacency matrix is:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1
0 1 1 0
```

code to create graph (nodes have the same color):

```
 Graph<Integer, String> g;
/** Creates a new instance of SimpleGraphView */
public ReadFile(int nbsommet,int [] [] nodeMat) {
    // Graph<V, E> where V is the type of the vertices and E is the type of the edges
    // Note showing the use of a SparseGraph rather than a SparseMultigraph
    g = new SparseGraph<Integer, String>();
    // Add some vertices. From above we defined these to be type Integer.
    /*for (int i = 1; i <=nbsommet; i++) {
        g.addVertex((Integer)i);

    }*/
       for (int i = 1; i <=nbsommet; i++)
       {  g.addVertex((Integer)i);
           for (int j = 1; j<=nbsommet; j++) 
           {
               if((nodeMat[i][j]==1)&& (j>i))
               {   if(!(g.getVertices().contains(j)))
               { g.addVertex((Integer)j);}
                   g.addEdge(i+" "+j, i, j);
                   }

    }}}
//...
  ReadFile sgv = new ReadFile(nbsommet,nodeMatfinal); // This builds the graph
  //Design sgv1 = new Design(); 
    Layout<Integer, String> layout = new KKLayout (sgv.g);
    //TreeLayout  layout = new TreeLayout(sgv.g,100,100);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(800,800));  
    BasicVisualizationServer<Integer, String> vv = new   BasicVisualizationServer<Integer, String>(layout);

    Transformer<Integer,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer,Paint>() {
        public Paint transform(Integer i) {
            return (Paint) Color.GREEN;
        }
    };  

    vv.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(850,850));
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelRenderer(new        DefaultVertexLabelRenderer(Color.green));
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(Color.white));
    vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(new ConstantTransformer(new BasicStroke(2.5f)));

    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer((Transformer<Integer, java.awt.Paint>) vertexPaint);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(new PickableVertexPaintTransformer<Integer>(vv.getPickedVertexState(), Color.green, Color.yellow));

    vv.setBackground(Color.gray);
    vv.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller<Integer>());
    vv.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);


    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(vv); 
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

So how change this code to have the connected components with different colors

Comment: @user2699285 Do you have a problem with using JUNG? What have you tried so far? Please include your code.

Answer (score 1):

The JUNG library does not let you set different renderers per Vertex, so instead you use one renderer and put some of the logic there. (I got that idea from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8460332/812149)).

You now have to determine which vertices should get which colors, and put that either in a method call or a `Map<Integer, Color>`. I will assume the latter:

```
final Map<Integer,Color> colorMapping = new HashMap<Integer, Color>();

// .....

Transformer<Integer,Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer,Paint>() 
{
    public Paint transform(Integer i)
    {
        return colorMapping.get(i.intValue());
    }
};
```

Obviously this leaves the question how to fill `colorMapping`.
You need to determine which are the connected components from the adjacency matrix; this is a separate problem that has been handled in [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8124626/812149).
Once you have the separate subgraphs, all that is left to do is to assign colors to them, and fill `colorMapping` accordingly.

---

A few notes on your code sample:

1. I had to comment this call out:

   `vv.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(new PickableVertexPaintTransformer<Integer>(vv.getPickedVertexState(), Color.green, Color.yellow));`

   It sets a new PaintTransformer that replaces the one that calls `vertexPaint`.
2. Your graph initialization is 1-based, but the array is 0-based. You should change

   `if((nodeMat[i][j]==1)&& (j>i))`

   into

   `if((nodeMat[i-1][j-1]==1)&& (j>i))`

   or you will get an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.