# How to Change Colour of an Edge in JUNG graph Visualization Library?

Tags: graph, jung, jung2

in reference to this Link : 
[Change Size/Color of Vertex in JUNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458970/change-size-color-of-vertex-in-jung)

I am trying to simulate Dijkstra algorithm visually using JUNG.  i can get set of Edges and end points of each Edge using built in Dijkstra algorithm in library. but my question is if i want to change the color of shortest path(Color of Edges and vertices in shortest path) at run-time how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Transformer<String, Paint> edgePaint = new Transformer<String, Paint>() {

    @Override

    public Paint transform(String s) {    // s represents the edge

             if (...){    // your condition
                 return Color.RED;
             }
             else {
                 return Color.DARK_GRAY;
             }
        }
    };

 // vv is the VirtualizationViewer
 vv.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(edgePaint);
```

`