# How to change color of an element in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graph, jframe, jung

I have a program to visualize a weighted adjacency matrix into a graph. I wish to change the color of 2 nodes alone.

[image]

In this graph, I wish to change the color of node 1 and 2.

Here is the code:

```
package graphvisualisation;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import org.apache.commons.collections15.Transformer;

import edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout.CircleLayout;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.Graph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.UndirectedSparseGraph;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.graph.util.EdgeType;
import edu.uci.ics.jung.visualization.BasicVisualizationServer;
import java.awt.Font;


public class GraphVisualisation
{
static int edgeCount_Directed = 0;   // This works with the inner MyEdge class
class MyNode 
{
  //static int edgeCount = 0;   // This works with the inner MyEdge class
  String id;
  public MyNode(String id) 
  {
  this.id = id;
  }
  public String toString() 
  {    
  return "V"+id;  
  } 
  public String Node_Property()
  {
   String node_prop = id;
   return(node_prop);
  }
}

class MyLink 
{

    int weight;
   String Label;
   int id;


   public MyLink(int weight)
   {
    this.id = edgeCount_Directed++;
    this.weight = weight;
   } 

   public String toString() 
   {
    return "E"+id;
   }
   public String Link_Property()
   {
    String Link_prop = Label;
    return(Link_prop);
   }
   public String Link_Property_wt()
   {
    String Link_prop_wt = ""+weight;
    return(Link_prop_wt);
   }
}
//used to construct graph and call graph algorithm used in JUNG

public void Visualize_Directed_Graph(LinkedList<String> Distinct_nodes, LinkedList<String> source_vertex, LinkedList<String> target_vertex, LinkedList<Integer> Edge_Weight)
{
//CREATING weighted directed graph
        Graph<MyNode, MyLink> g = new UndirectedSparseGraph<GraphVisualisation.MyNode, GraphVisualisation.MyLink>();
        //create node objects
        Hashtable<String, MyNode> Graph_Nodes = new Hashtable<String, GraphVisualisation.MyNode>();
        LinkedList<MyNode> Source_Node = new LinkedList<GraphVisualisation.MyNode>();
        LinkedList<MyNode> Target_Node = new LinkedList<GraphVisualisation.MyNode>();
        LinkedList<MyNode> Graph_Nodes_Only = new LinkedList<GraphVisualisation.MyNode>();
        //LinkedList<MyLink> Graph_Links = new LinkedList<Graph_Algos.MyLink>();
        //create graph nodes
        for(int i=0;i<Distinct_nodes.size();i++)
        {
        String node_name = Distinct_nodes.get(i);
        MyNode data = new MyNode(node_name);
        Graph_Nodes.put(node_name, data);
        Graph_Nodes_Only.add(data);
        }
        //Now convert all source and target nodes into objects
        for(int t=0;t<source_vertex.size();t++)
        {
        Source_Node.add(Graph_Nodes.get(source_vertex.get(t)));
        Target_Node.add(Graph_Nodes.get(target_vertex.get(t)));
        }
        //Now add nodes and edges to the graph
        for(int i=0;i<Edge_Weight.size();i++)
        {
        g.addEdge(new MyLink(Edge_Weight.get(i)),Source_Node.get(i), Target_Node.get(i), EdgeType.UNDIRECTED);
        }

        //-------------

          CircleLayout<MyNode, MyLink> layout1 = new CircleLayout<MyNode,MyLink>(g);

           layout1.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
           BasicVisualizationServer<MyNode, MyLink> viz = new BasicVisualizationServer<MyNode,MyLink>(layout1);

           viz.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 350));

           Transformer<MyNode, String> vertexLabelTransformer = new Transformer<MyNode,String>() {
             public String transform(MyNode vertex) {
               return (String) vertex.Node_Property();
             }
           };
     //Sets the vertex label font
     Transformer<MyNode,Font> vertexFont = new Transformer<MyNode,Font>() {
         public Font transform(MyNode node) {
             Font font = new Font("Sans Serif", Font.BOLD, 30 );
             return font;
         }
     };

           Transformer<MyLink, String> edgeLabelTransformer = new Transformer<MyLink, String>() {
             public String transform(MyLink edge) {
               return  edge.Link_Property_wt();
             }
           };

           Transformer<MyLink,Font> edgeFont = new Transformer<MyLink,Font>() {
         public Font transform(MyLink node) {
             Font font = new Font("Sans Serif", Font.PLAIN, 25);
             return font;
         }
           };
           viz.getRenderContext().setEdgeLabelTransformer(edgeLabelTransformer);
           viz.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(vertexLabelTransformer);
           viz.getRenderContext().setVertexFontTransformer(vertexFont);
           viz.getRenderContext().setEdgeFontTransformer(edgeFont);

           JFrame frame = new JFrame("Graph Visualisation");
           frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
           frame.getContentPane().add(viz);
           frame.pack();
           frame.setVisible(true);

}

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {


    GraphVisualisation GA1 = new GraphVisualisation();

     LinkedList<String> Distinct_Vertex = new LinkedList<String>();//used to enter vertexes
     LinkedList<String> Source_Vertex = new LinkedList<String>();
     LinkedList<String> Target_Vertex = new LinkedList<String>();
     //LinkedList<Double> Edge_Weight = new LinkedList<Double>();//used to enter edge weight
     LinkedList<Integer> Edge_Weight = new LinkedList<Integer>();//used to enter edge weight

     int[][] adj_matrix={{0,4,0,0,10},{4,0,6,2,0},{0,6,0,4,0},{0,2,4,0,0},{10,0,0,0,0}};

     int i,j;
     //add disinct vertex
     for(i=0;i<adj_matrix.length;i++)
     {
         Distinct_Vertex.add(Integer.toString(i+1));
     }


     //add edges
     for(i=0;i<adj_matrix.length;i++)
     {
         for(j=0;j<adj_matrix.length;j++)
         {
             if(adj_matrix[i][j]>0)
             {
             Source_Vertex.add(Integer.toString(i+1)); Target_Vertex.add(Integer.toString(j+1)); Edge_Weight.add((int)adj_matrix[i][j]);
             }
         }
     }

     GA1.Visualize_Directed_Graph(Distinct_Vertex, Source_Vertex, Target_Vertex, Edge_Weight);

     }
}
```

The program is made using JUNG library. The adjacency matrix is the input and the graph is obtained as the output in a JFrame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Size/Color of Vertex in JUNG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458970/change-size-color-of-vertex-in-jung)

Comment: Please post [mcve]. Many chunks of this code are not essential to illustrate the question. To make your code easy to read, please follow [Java Naming Conventions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-naming-conventions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this:

```
Transformer<Integer, Paint> vertexPaint = new Transformer<Integer, Paint>() {
    public Paint transform(Integer i) {
        if (i == wantedVertex) {
            return Color.WHITE; // Example of color from java.awt.Color
        }
        else {
            return Color.BLACK;
        }
    }
};

viz.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(vertexPaint);
```

[The sample program in this article](https://www.vainolo.com/2011/02/15/learning-jung-3-changing-the-vertexs-shape/) demonstrates another way of how to change a vertex's color (and also how to change its shape).

Comment: Thank you. But, I am getting an error, " Paint cannot be resolved into a type".

Comment: @AmudhanManisekaran add line `import java.awt.Paint;`